# How does new operator overloaded in the example work without passing the size of memory to be allocated?

Tags: c++, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

In the below example taken from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/cpp/cpp/new-and-delete-operators?view=vs-2017 how does the new operator know the value of `stAllocateBlock` when it is never passed in the call:

```
Blanks *a5 = new(0xa5) Blanks;
```

And what is the actual implementation of the `operator new` in the global scope. How does it call the constructor of the specific object being created and what parameters does it take.

```
// spec1_the_operator_new_function1.cpp  
#include <malloc.h>  
#include <memory.h>  

class Blanks  
{  
public:  
    Blanks(){}  
    void *operator new( size_t stAllocateBlock, char chInit );  
};  
void *Blanks::operator new( size_t stAllocateBlock, char chInit )  
{  
    void *pvTemp = malloc( stAllocateBlock );  
    if( pvTemp != 0 )  
        memset( pvTemp, chInit, stAllocateBlock );  
    return pvTemp;  
}  
// For discrete objects of type Blanks, the global operator new function  
// is hidden. Therefore, the following code allocates an object of type  
// Blanks and initializes it to 0xa5  
int main()  
{  
   Blanks *a5 = new(0xa5) Blanks;  
   return a5 != 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike with other operators, where an expression involving that operator effectively maps directly to a corresponding `operator` function call, a [*new-expression*](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new) is more than just one way to call an `operator new` function. The purpose of a *new-expression* is to create an object of some type. There's more to creating an object of some type than simply deciding which piece of memory that object should live in. For example, constructors might have to be called. A *new-expression* may use an [allocation function](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.dynamic.allocation) (i.e., an `operator new` function) to allocate storage. But not every *new-expression* necessarily has to call an allocation function. [In some situations](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#10), the compiler is allowed to omit calls to allocation functions, e.g., to coalesce multiple allocations into a single one. So in the end, the compiler decides when to allocate memory for what. It calls an `operator new` function to handle the actual memory allocation. And when it does so, it knows how much memory to request based on which objects are going to be created in that storage. And it will pass that size of the request as the first argument to the `operator new` function. That first argument is always present, the stuff you write in parentheses after the `new` in a *new-expression* will simply be passed as arguments in addition to that implicit first one…

Answer (score 0):

It's calculated fron the size of the object being allocated. In the expression

```
Blanks *a5 = new(0xa5) Blanks;
```

`stAllocateBlock` will be `sizeof(Blanks)`

Answer (score 0):

You name the type `Blanks` in `new(0xa5) Blanks`. It's not difficult for the implementation to pass at least `sizeof(Blanks)` automatically. In fact, it's exactly what it does.

This is also why the overloaded `operator new` works correctly with derived classes. For instance:

```
struct D : Blanks { char dummy[2]; };
```

If you were to do `new(0xa5) D`, then the implementation would pass `sizeof(D)`, because that's the most derived class type that statically appears in the new expression.